# Adding Multiple value setAttribute on pop up onclick in an input

Tags: javascript, onclick, setattribute

I am stack in a problem solving javascript and I need to ask advice regarding my project. I have an input Called Subject and Level, in level i want to add multiple values seperated via comma,

I created this function

```
function selectedLvl($levels){
    lvl1.setAttribute("value", $levels);
    }
```

In my pop up I have this code where user click it and it is updated the input. For now its working but only one value. How can i add multiple keys seprated in comma, Example if they clcik each vallue it will append like All Levels, Kindergarten, Primary School and so on..

```
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('All Levels')">All Levels</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Kindergarten')">Kindergarten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Primary School')">Primary School</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('School Years 7,8,9')">School Years 7,8,9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('GCSE – Middle School')">GCSE – Middle School</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('HKDSE')">HKDSE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('IB, AS/A, Senior Secondary')">IB, AS/A, Senior Secondary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Tertiary Level')">Tertiary Level
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Test Preparation')">Test Preparation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Computer/IT')">Computer/IT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Language Classes')">Language Classes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Business Training')">Business Training</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want lvl1 to be an array, or an object where the value is an array.

With lvl1 as an array:

```js
var lvl1=[];
function selectedLvl($levels){
    lvl1.push( $levels);
    console.log(lvl1);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('All Levels')">All Levels</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Kindergarten')">Kindergarten</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Primary School')">Primary School</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('School Years 7,8,9')">School Years 7,8,9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('GCSE – Middle School')">GCSE – Middle School</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('HKDSE')">HKDSE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('IB, AS/A, Senior Secondary')">IB, AS/A, Senior Secondary</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Tertiary Level')">Tertiary Level
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Test Preparation')">Test Preparation</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Computer/IT')">Computer/IT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Language Classes')">Language Classes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Business Training')">Business Training</a></li>
</ul>
```

With lvl1 as an object:

```js
var lvl1={};
lvl1.values=[];
function selectedLvl($levels){
    var temp=lvl1.values;
    temp.push( $levels);
    lvl1.values=temp;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(lvl1));
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('All Levels')">All Levels</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Kindergarten')">Kindergarten</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Primary School')">Primary School</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('School Years 7,8,9')">School Years 7,8,9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('GCSE – Middle School')">GCSE – Middle School</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('HKDSE')">HKDSE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('IB, AS/A, Senior Secondary')">IB, AS/A, Senior Secondary</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Tertiary Level')">Tertiary Level
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Test Preparation')">Test Preparation</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Computer/IT')">Computer/IT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Language Classes')">Language Classes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectedLvl('Business Training')">Business Training</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks men your awesome im new in javascript but you open my mind more in programming. Goodvibes cheers

Comment: Hi Man one last question i already put it in a value it is great because once they click it is added now like an array but one question is there any way that we can only added once, once they click it they cannot add in the second click i dont know if that is possible

Comment: Do you want to just hide the li from the user?